# Statement with multiple conditions not returning expected behavior in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I work in ASP.NET c# and MySQL database.

In the field `doDate` of my database table I can have three values :

> 1. Null
> 2. 0000-00-00
> 3. 2016-03-08

I need when the values of field doDate are :

> 1. 0000-00-00
> 2. 2016-03-08

Disabled the **TextBox** `txtdoDate` and I have tried this :

```
    txtdoDate1 = dr["doDate"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["doDate"] == "0000-00-00" ? "0000-00-00" : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["doDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    if (txtdoDate1.ToString() != "")
    {
        txtdoDate.Text = txtdoDate1.ToString();
        txtdoDate.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txtdoDate.Enabled = true;
    }
```

But when the values of field `doDate` is :

> 0000-00-00

the **TextBox** `txtdoDate` is enabled and empty.

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

```
protected void loadsRecord()
{
    using (OdbcConnection cn =
    new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sql = @" SELECT ..... ; ";

        using (OdbcCommand command =
                new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {

                txtdoDate1 = dr["doDate"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : (dr["doDate"] == "0000-00-00" ? "0000-00-00" : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["doDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

                if (txtdoDate1.ToString() != "")
                   {
                      txtdoDate.Text = txtdoDate1.ToString();
                      txtdoDate.Enabled = false;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      txtdoDate.Enabled = true;
                   }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column doDate?

Comment: @Steve Thanks, the datatype of the column doDate is `date`

Comment: I am a bit perplexed. This could not work at the loading of the data from the database. The value '0000-00-00' is not a valid NET DateTime value and you should get an error when you load this. Could you show the code that loads this record from the database?

Comment: @Steve: Please see **Edit #1** in my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct behavior because you are using the following `if` statement

```
if (txtdoDate1.ToString() != "")
{
    txtdoDate.Text = txtdoDate1.ToString();
    txtdoDate.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
   txtdoDate.Enabled = true;
}
```

When `dr["doDate"] == "0000-00-00"` the value stored in `txtdoDate` is `"0000-00-00"` which is not `txtdoDate1.ToString() != ""`. You have to modify the condition in the `if` statement like this:

```
if (txtdoDate1.ToString() != "" && txtdoDate1.ToString() != "0000-00-00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
txtdoDate1 = dr["doDate"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : (dr["doDate"] == "0000-00-00" ? "0000-00-00" : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["doDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Enclose the second clause in parantheses

Comment: Thank you but I don't have change in the return.